# Is it possible to view a package information from terminal before installing it?

Tags: package-management

I was wondering if it was possible to check information about a package before installing it without needing to open a web browser to look for it there.

For example, say I type in

```
~$ asdf
```

Then I see recommended packages:

```
No command 'asdf' found, did you mean:
 Command 'asdfg' from package 'aoeui' (universe)
 Command 'sadf' from package 'sysstat' (main)
 Command 'sdf' from package 'sdf' (universe)
asdf: command not found
```

Say I want to find out what the package 'sdf' does. Can I find this information in terminal, or will I have to do it the slow way and look it up online?

Comment: This is one of the many uses of a package manager. In ubuntu's case, this is probably `apt-get`. You can use it's options to query information about available packages and then, if desired, install them.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The main package management tool suite of Ubuntu is called [APT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool).

Since Ubuntu 14.04, you can use the [`apt`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=apt&apropos=0&sektion=8&manpath=Debian+unstable+sid&format=html&locale=en) command:

```
apt show sdf
```

Earlier releases do not have this command. You can use [`apt-cache`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/apt-cache.8.html) to obtain information about available packages, and [`apt-get`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/apt-get.8.html) to perform actions such as installing packages.

```
apt-cache show sdf
```

[Aptitude](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/aptitude.8.html) is a more advanced interface to package manipulation (existing both as a command line tool and a full-screen text mode interactive tool). You need to install the [aptitude](http://packages.ubuntu.com/aptitude) package.

```
aptitude show sdf
```

Comment: I learned something!  The updated apt command is long overdue.

Answer (score 20):

In Ubuntu(debian based), you may run `apt-cache show package` command to view all the information about the package. Also run `apt-cache showpkg package`
, `apt-cache policy package` to get additional infos.

Example:

```
$ apt-cache show sdf
Package: sdf
Priority: extra
Section: universe/text
Installed-Size: 1415
Maintainer: Colin Watson <cjwatson@debian.org>
Architecture: all
Version: 2.001+1-3
Depends: perl
Suggests: sdf-doc, perl-doc, htmldoc, texlive-latex-base, ghostscript, sgmltools-lite
Filename: pool/universe/s/sdf/sdf_2.001+1-3_all.deb
Size: 294288
MD5sum: 49f9370b17567bae8a362d83633ffb66
SHA1: 967da4edf9948bb9393db34bd1f8037a840bd335
SHA256: 968769e7c75d1612f4f3c4b26c49532b26f288fd8ee722c2d83ba807620e0df5
Description-en: Simple Document Parser
 SDF (Simple Document Format) is a freely available document development
 system which generates high quality outputs in a variety of formats
 from a single source. The output formats supported include
 PostScript(tm), PDF, HTML, plain text, POD, man pages, LaTeX,
 MIF, SGML, Windows(tm) help, RTF, MIMS F6 help and MIMS HTX help.
 If the idea of specifying documents in a logical manner via a
 simple markup language sounds appealing, SDF may be useful to you.
Description-md5: 65eb1315794ec8133dd1a14b0e8db243
Multi-Arch: foreign
```

Comment: And what about non-Debian based Linux/Unix systems?